# html text field to have pre appended text which is not modifiable

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have a text field which has pre appended text which is not modifiable.
So when user tries to add text it starts after the pre text.
Also when the form is submitted it should not pass the pre appended text. Its mainly for display purpose but within the text field. I have attached the image which will clarify my question further. For example I would like to add "$" as pre text in the image below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: the $ is dynamic text and so could not be image.

[image]

Comment: You cannot use :before and content with an input, because it has no content. (EDIT: The comment to which that was directed has been deleted).

Comment: if you don't need much in terms of accessibility, would a background image be enough?

Comment: Couldn't you just put the text outside of the input element? Why do you need it to be inside the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4A7Q/) with two solutions, both using CSS.

The first uses a data URI of a PNG that contains a dollar sign for the background image of the text input. The second uses a label containing a dollar sign and shifts it over to be on top of the input (you probably should use a span instead of a label, for accessibility's sake).

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="bob" />
<br/>
<label for="fred">$</label><input type="text" id="fred" />
```

CSS:

```
#bob {
    background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgBAMAAACBVGfHAAAAG1BMVEX///8AAAC/v7/f398/Pz8fHx9/f3+fn59fX19QuZN1AAAAbElEQVQokWNgGFyASRiN7ygYhiKgGCYW6IAs4KgsYCqELCDKLMCehCwQyCyAamhjM5qAiaC4AqpIiaAoqgizuKMQqoAAuwgytxxoiyiSABvQHcwoKgSVBVjEkI1IlEDzCzu6bxnQnY4pQFsAAC/cCbAPkBI2AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding-left: 1.1em;
}

label[for="fred"] {
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: smaller;
}

#fred {
    padding-left: 1.2em;
}
```

Both of these methods are hacky. A JS solution would be more involved, but handle much more nicely (I just don't have time to implement one).

Comment: Thank you for the great solution. Second options works great for me. Can you please explain why is this hacky solution. What is the drawback as I do not see any issue with second option.

Comment: I consider this a hack because of the way you have to position manually. It will be hard to get right across all browsers and platforms. Before using this solution, I would change the label to a span (and the 'for' to a 'class') _and_ position the input a little left. You can see in the example that there is a space left of the input where the dollar sign was.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat way using `background-image`
http://jsfiddle.net/dxu2s/1/

HTML:

```
<label for="RefundAmount">Enter a refund amount: </label>
<input type="text" name="RefundAmount" id="RefundAmount">
```

CSS:

```
#RefundAmount {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #FFF url(http://oi57.tinypic.com/nmncz5.jpg) no-repeat left center;
}
```

I've also tried using the css psuedo-element `:before` but it didn't work as input tags doesn't have content in em'.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I cannot use the image for "$" sign and has to be text. Do you have easier solution for text as you gave for image. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Tejas I see, the easiest solution for text would be to add another label containing the `$` and position it manually (similar to what unclekyky did)
http://jsfiddle.net/dxu2s/4/

Answer (score 1):

This is a class i wrote you can use it for free, i didnt test it a lot. if you find a bug let me know

HTML:  <input type="text" id="inputA" value="$" />

in script add this Class constructor

```
//***************************************************************
//-------------------------------------- Class halfEditable_INPUT
//***************************************************************
//-- divides an Input into an non editable area from 0 to index, but not including the index, the rest is editable

//-----------------------------------------------------
//-------- constructor
//----------------------------------------------------- 
function halfEditable_INPUT (inputField,index)
    {
    if (typeof index=="undefined") index=inputField.value.length;

    //------------------------------------ PUBLIC Objects, Properties
    this.element=inputField; 
    this.index=index;

    //-- a reference to the instance of the halfEditable_INPUT class saved in the html element, to get instance values in DOM events
    Object.defineProperty (inputField,"halfEditable_instance",{value:this,writable: false, enumerable:true, configurable:true});     

    //-- get the value of the input directly
    Object.defineProperty (this,"value",                      {get:this.PRIVATE_getValue,set:this.PRIVATE_setValue});

    inputField.addEventListener ("keydown",this.PRIVATE_checkStatus_ONKEYDOWN);
    }

//-----------------------------------------------------
//-------- prototype
//-----------------------------------------------------

//------------------------------------ PRIVATE Methods

/*  this      ---    points to the input field
        checks if the cursorPosition is in the non Editable area or is at the limit Point
        if it is at the limitPoint - dont allow backspace or cursor left
        if it is inside allow nothing and move cursorPosition to the limit
        reset the Position1 key to index  */
halfEditable_INPUT.prototype.PRIVATE_checkStatus_ONKEYDOWN=function (event)
    {
    var keyCode=event.keyCode;
    var index=this.halfEditable_instance.index;
    var selectionStart=this.selectionStart, selectionEnd=this.selectionEnd;

    if (keyCode==36) //-- position1 key
        {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setSelectionRange (index,index);
        return;
        }

    if (selectionStart<index)
        {
        if (selectionEnd>index) this.setSelectionRange (index,selectionEnd);
        else this.setSelectionRange (index,index);
        }
    else if (selectionStart==index) {if (keyCode==8 || keyCode==37) event.preventDefault();} //-- backspace, left cursor
    }

halfEditable_INPUT.prototype.PRIVATE_setValue=function (value) {this.element.value=value;}
halfEditable_INPUT.prototype.PRIVATE_getValue=function () {return this.element.value;}

//-----------------------------------------------------
//-------- prototype    -- END
//-----------------------------------------------------

//***************************************************************
//-------------------------------------- Class halfEditable_INPUT -- END
//***************************************************************

var inputA=new halfEditable_INPUT(document.getElementById ("inputA"));
```

if you have further questions let me know.